# openmp/C++ simple parallel region returns incosistent results

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

So I am trying to learn the OpenMP API, I have the basics down, but this part has got me confused: (testable code!)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <omp.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;
const int col = 10, row = 10;
int c[][11] = {{-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
               {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
               {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
               {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
               {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
               {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
               {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
               {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
               {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
               {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
               {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}  };

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
int temp[3] = {-1, -1, -1};
int id;
for (unsigned short i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    #pragma omp parallel shared(c) firstprivate(i) private(temp)  
    {
        #pragma ivdep
        #pragma omp for schedule(static, 1) //private(id)//,m_i, ind)
        for(unsigned short j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            // calculate c
            /*  old
            temp[0] = c[i-1][j-1]+3;
            temp[1] = c[i-1][j]-4;
            temp[2] = c[i][j-1]-5;
            c[i][j] = temp[0]; 
            c[i][j] = temp[1];
            c[i][j] = temp[2];
            */
            temp[0] = c[i][j-1]+3;
            c[i][j] = temp[0]; 
        }
    }
}
// print c
for (int i = 0; i< row + 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j< col + 1; j++)
    {
        cout << c[i][j] << "/";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
 } // end main
```

I believe the code is self explanatory, I only want to add that I want to only parallelize the inner loop because I want the outer loop to be used with dependencies in `c` array.

Also `row` & `col` variables can be used to control the array's dimensions.

I use this bash script to run the whole thing

```
#!/bin/bash
g++ -O0 -o xx par_test.cpp -fopenmp
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 # or 2 or 4
./xx
```

But the output differs when I use more than one 1 thread.
Output for `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` (consistent) 
[image]

Output for `OMP_NUM_THREADS=2` (every execution returns something different)
[image]

Output for `OMP_NUM_THREADS=4` (every execution returns something different)
[image]

Things I also tried:

- with & without vectorization (i.e. with & without the #pragma ivdep)
- `threadprivate(temp)`
  With no luck here either.

Since the single thread execution always has the same output, I am fairly sure that there is a problem with my variable sharing, nevertheles it eludes me..

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: you are using openmp AND simd instructions. This might go wrong. Try to remove the #pragma ivdep

Comment: @hr0m from my understanding the `#pragma ivdep` suggests to the compiler that the next loop could be vectorized is it not? so if i remove it no vectorization will take place (i.e. done that already). Anyhow as I've mentioned above I have tried it both with & without this particular `#pragma` but the behaviour stays the same - the code is testable btw.

Comment: omfg i am so blind!!!
You have dependencies within the loop itself!!! I don't know why you are using temps. If you are changing c[i][j], it might be changed in a previous step already. Remember you are parallel!

Comment: Parallelise the outer loop, not the inner one, because of the loop-carried dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a parallel loop over `j` here:

```
    #pragma omp for schedule(static, 1)
    for(unsigned short j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        // calculate c
        temp[0] = c[i][j-1]+3;
        c[i][j] = temp[0]; 
    }
```

You refer to cell `c[i][j-1]`, but it is possible that this value is being calculated in another thread. How can you be sure that this has already happened?

Comment: Oh now I see.. So basically, the calculations will be correct, so long I don't use a cell of `c` that is calculated in the same j loop (i.e. if I use `c[i-1][j]` instead of `c[i][j-1]` all would be fine?)

Comment: Yes, that is correct, because that one is not changed in the loop.

Comment: or even if i used a fixed cell of `c` (e.g. `c[0][0]` ) instead, for the calculation, it should still compute correctly? So, I only have to regulate the writes to a cell & not the reads?

Comment: You have to take into account which values are being changed in the loop, if you use those for computation. If one of your threads changes `c[0][0]` and one of the others uses it for computation, then you are in trouble.